# How to set up a dev environment for Active Directory project?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm looking for any hints or suggestions on setting up a Dev machine for doing some Active Directory programming.

I do not have access to a full network with a domain controller most of the time and I would like to isolate myself from production networks anyway.

I did download the 180 day trial of Win server 2012 VHD and was trying to set it up in a VM but I am not a sys admin so got a little lost and was hoping someone would have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can get your development tools installed on the 2012 vhd, active directory. Alternatively you could sign up for a free trial of azure and use this step by step guide to configure Active directory.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/17/step-by-step-building-a-windows-server-2012-active-directory-forest-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure.aspx

For a non cloud solution

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12370.set-up-your-first-root-windows-server-2012-domain-controller-step-by-step.aspx